# DB backup in cron is creating a file with zero byte

Tags: database, cron, command, server, backup

I have set up a cron in my godaddy server for taking DB backup. For Testing purpose, I run the cron in every minute. The command is :

```
mysqldump tuniv_results > /home/username/public_html/DB-VVS/tuniv_results.sql
```

In my DB-VVS folder one file, tuniv_results.sql, is creating but it is of zero byte. Could you please let me know the issue, why it is not creating properly?
Thanks in advance.

------------UPDATE-------------------

```
$user="****";
$password="****";
$database="*****";

$dumpCommand='/usr/bin/mysqldump';
$dumpCommand.=" -e -f -h <ipaddress> -u$user -p$password";
$dumpCommand.=" $database";
$dumpCommand.=" > bekap.sql";

$results=$dumpCommand;
exec($dumpCommand);
echo "result: ".$results;
```

I create a file in the root folder and put the absolute path of that file in the Command text-field as /home/username/cronfile.php. But in the root file there is no file like `bekap.sql`. Please let me know what might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
$user="*********";
$password="*****";
$database="*********";

$dumpCommand='/usr/bin/mysqldump';
$dumpCommand.=" -e -f -h host.name.com -u$user -p$password";
$dumpCommand.=" $database";
$dumpCommand.=" > bekap.sql";

$results=$dumpCommand;
exec($dumpCommand);
echo "result: ".$results;
```

Another solution :

I think this will help to you.

Open terminal and type:
sudo tcsh

pico /etc/crontab
or
nano /etc/crontab

And add one of the following lines depending on your situation. This schedule the backup on 1am every day.

Remote Host Backup with linked PATH to mysqldump:

0 1 * * * mysqldump -h mysql.host.com -uusername -ppassword --opt database > /path/to/directory/filename.sql

Remote Host Backup:

0 1 * * * /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h mysql.host.com -uusername -ppassword --opt database > /path/to/directory/filename.sql

Local Host mysql Backup:

0 1 * * * /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --opt database > /path/to/directory/filename.sql

(There is no space between the -p and password or -u and username - replace root with a correct database username.)

Comment: How to use this? shall I have to create a file and run that file in cron?

Comment: IN cron set up, how to add that file? Shall I put the absolute path of the file in the command text-field?

Comment: put this in your root folder

Comment: check my updated answer for doing this through command. I have not tested but i hope this will work

Comment: instead of mysql.host.com should I use localhost or ipaddress?

Comment: I have cpanel details. Can I do that from there directly. Because I have not sudo password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94400/discussion-between-srim-and-lalji-nakum).